# Efficient way to pull data from second database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, multiple-databases

We have a primary database where all of our app resides.

But there's a second database (updated from an external source), that I'd like to be able to connect to so I can pull data from it. I don't need to write anything...just read.

It also only has one table that I'm pulling from.

I really just need to do something like:

```
OtherDatabase.articles.where(id > 1000)
```

And that's it.

So how can I do this in Rails (running 3.2.13)?

Comment: Note that if you truly care about not writing to the existing DB, you should connect with credentials that have only been granted limited read permissions.  I.E., don't rely on this application's code to enforce the other application's permissions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For simple scenarios, Rails can support this without any extra gems; simply define the database in database.yml:

```
other_db:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: other_db
  username: user
  password: passwd
  host: 1.2.3.4
  port: 3306
```

Then in the model you want to use the other database add:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:other_db)
  self.table_name = 'other_db.articles'
end
```

And then you can perform your query:

```
Article.where("id > 1000")
```

=)

Comment: After I get it work, I realize that the arguments of two method is different. You need to send `establish_connection(:other_db)` the connection name, which is first line of database.yml example. But `self.table_name = 'other_db.articles'` need the real database name which is 4th line of database.yml.

Comment: thanks ..here i'm using the code on october 2023

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we need to define the external database:

```
# config/database.yml
external:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/external.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

For something like this, I prefer using a module that takes care of database connections.

```
# lib/database.rb
module Database
  def self.using(db, klass=ActiveRecord::Base)
    klass.establish_connection(db.to_sym)
    result = yield if block_given?
    klass.establish_connection(Rails.env.to_sym)
    result
  end
end
```

By passing a block to a module like this we can make sure we don't bleed our queries into a database where they don't belong or forget to revert our connection. Also, we default to ActiveRecord::Base so that we can work with any of our models. However, if we know we're only using one and want to isolate our model usage, we can pass it as the secondary parameter.

The resulting implementation can look something like this:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def read_remote
    Database.using(:external) do
      account = Account.where(active: true)
      account.users
    end
  end
end
```

Now we have a nice and clean block we can use anywhere we like, use any models we want inside the block and always be operating on the extneral database. Once that block is finished, we know we're working back on our original database.

Comment: Seems like overkill since `Account` always connects to the same database (in the OP's case). But it looks like an interesting approach to connecting a single model to multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Paste:

For a single-master situation, you could define another database connection in database.yml for the read slave:

```
read_slave:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: read_only_production
  username: user
  password: pass
  host: read_slave_host
```

This database is backed by a module, which mirrors the ActiveRecord classes using this database connection:

```
require 'magic_multi_connections'
module ReadSlave
  establish_connection :read_slave
end
```

Now, all pre-existing models can be accessed through the read_slave connection by prefixing the model class with ReadSlave::.

```
# use the read-only connection
    @user = ReadSlave::User.find(params[:id])

    # write to the master (can't use @user.update_attributes because it would#
    try to write to the read slave)
    User.update(@user.id, :login => "new_login")
```